# How do I call another method from the main method?

Tags: java, jdbc

```
package Simple;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.ParseException;

import java.util.LinkedList;


public class CheckJdbc {


     private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db";
     private static final String DB_USER = "root";
     private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "root";
     private static int RECORD_COUNT = 1;
     int days=1;

  static int total=1;
  public static java.util.LinkedList searchBetweenDates(java.util.Date startDate, java.util.Date endDate) {

      java.util.Date begin = new Date(startDate.getTime());
      java.util.LinkedList list = new java.util.LinkedList();
      list.add(new Date(begin.getTime()));
      java.util.Date end = new Date(endDate.getTime());
      endDate.setTime(endDate.getTime() + 24*3600*1000);

           while(begin.compareTo(endDate)<0){
           list.add(new Date(begin.getTime()));
           Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
       int total=1;

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(startDate);

        for(int d=0; d<=total; d++)
        {
           cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
           timestamp = new Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime());
           String S = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(timestamp);

           String[] parts = S.split(" ");
      //   System.out.println("Date:" + parts[0]);
     //    System.out.println("Time:" + parts[1]);

           String date=parts[0];
           String time=parts[1];
               begin = new Date(begin.getTime() + 86400000);

          cal.setTime(endDate);

              System.out.println(timestamp);
          List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
          StringBuffer record = new StringBuffer();
              for (int i = 1; i <= RECORD_COUNT; i++) {

              records = new ArrayList<String>(RECORD_COUNT);
              int RECORD_COUNT= total;

        for (int j = 0; j < total; j++) {

                        int a2 = 220 + j % 30; // 230 - 244 by 1
        String wString = Integer.toString(a2);
        String a = String.valueOf(a2);   
        double b2 = 0.12 + j % 3.9 * 0.01 ; // 1.3 - 3.9 by 0.1 
        String aString = Double.toString(a2);
        String b = String.valueOf(b2);
        b = b.substring(0, Math.min(b.length(), 5));
        double c2 = 0.01 + j % 49 * 0.01 ; // 0.01 - 0.49 by 0.01
        String bString = Double.toString(c2);
        String c = String.valueOf(c2);
        c = c.substring(0, Math.min(c.length(), 5));         
          record.append(a + "," + b + "," + c + "," +date+ ","+ time );
          record.append("\t\t");

          record.append("\n");
          records.add(record.toString());  
          try {
              String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO cmd1"
              + "(a, b, c ,date, time) " + "VALUES"
              + "("+record.toString()+")";
              System.out.println("insertTableSQL - " + insertTableSQL);             

      insertRecordIntodb();
      Connection dbConnection = null;
      Statement statement = null;
      dbConnection = getDBConnection();
      statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
      statement.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL);
      System.out.println(insertTableSQL);
      System.out.println("Record is inserted into Db table!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
    }
  }
    }
  }

      }     

      return list;

  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


     //searchBetweenDates(d);
      java.util.LinkedList hitList = searchBetweenDates(
                new                    java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("01/10/2016"),
                new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("01/15/2016"));
            String[] combo = new String[hitList.size()];
            for(int i=0; i<hitList.size(); i++)
                combo[i] = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(((java.util.Date)hitList.get(i)));


  }   

private static void insertRecordIntodb() {

  }

  private static Connection getDBConnection() {
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    try {
      Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
      dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
      return dbConnection;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return dbConnection;
  }
}
```

I want to call data for date and time which is in searchBetweenDates method into main method. I have created object in main method but still its not fetching. What should i do for that? As its not fetching data from date and time.
I am getting following error:

```
insertTableSQL - INSERT INTO cmd1(a, b, c ,date, time) VALUES(220,0.12,0.01,01/10/2016,00:02:00     
)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':02:00   
)' at line 1
```

Comment: Please make your example smaller and concentrate only on the essential. Currently it is too complicated to read and understand.

Comment: Autoformatting could help a bit on the question. And the misusing of static is also strong in this one...

Comment: aside from that (without looking to deeply into the code) I think you're mixing up static functions and function calls on instances.

Comment: And make your code at least compilable. Then `startDate` and `endDate` are `null` when you run `searchBetweenDates()` method in your `main` method

Comment: i am java learner can you please mark my mistakes so that i can recognise easily to make changes

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code is not even valid Java code (i.e. it does not even compile). Secondly, you are calling a static method through an instance, which you shouldn't. Use:

```
Test.searchBetweenDates(startDate, endDate);
```

This, however won't make your code work per se, because `startDate` and `endDate` is `null`.

Comment: i tried that too still not working :(

Comment: What does not work? Can you compile it at least?

Comment: i want to print date and time along the values of a,b,c but mmy date and time are in searchBetweenDates() and its not appending in records.

Comment: Okay, I tried to make your code compile. It has so many compilation failures, that rewriting the whole thing would be easier. No offense, but you need to learn some OOP before writing JDBC code...

Comment: ok thanks i ll try

Comment: please specify where should i make changes to improve my self as i am beginner in java

Comment: Some things from the top of my head: learn what `static` means, and try not to misuse it; always use generics if you can (forget the raw LinkedList in the question); never run dynamic SQL with `Statement`, always use `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: oks thanks i ll try not to make same mistake again thanx for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        new Test().searchBetweenDates(startDate, endDate);
        searchBetweenDates(startDate, endDate);
```

the parenthesis is missing. It should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        new Test().searchBetweenDates(startDate, endDate);
        searchBetweenDates(startDate, endDate);
}
```

Comment: tried still not working ...

Comment: Not working is not a problem description.

Comment: i want to print date and time along the values of a,b,c but mmy date and time are in searchBetweenDates() and its not appending in records.

Comment: check how to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask